# Getting Instagram followers after policy changes on June 1, 2016

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Before the Instagram policy changes (which made on June 1, 2016) my application showed a list of all the following users' info of the logged in user. I get this by the following URL GET request:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

After the changes, I get a list of only the Sandbox users the logged on user is following after. (I added Sandbox user to keep developing this app).

But, in fact, I want to get **all** the users' info the logged on user is following after.

If it only happens in Sandbox environment it's OK but what about the production environment?

After I submitted my app, can I get **all** the following list? Or I'll get only the users who logged in to my app (like Facebook does)?

Thank You

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer to this, but it seems that the only option is to build an "application", go through the application process, and have all your users log in and authenticate the app :( Alternatively, web scraping :( I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Krisrak's answer is correct, sandbox mode is why you are not seeing results. Here's a bit more details on how it works:

NOTE: What follows is explained more clearly in [this summary of how the new Instagram API rules](https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.4z8g35g2s)

> “Sandbox mode” is the (unintuitively-named) gatekeeper walling off
>   most of what you want to do. This is the default status for all
>   clients, that have not undergone the strict submission process. An API
>   client in sandbox mode has extremely limited permissions. In fact, it
>   has fewer permissions than an anonymous user viewing public content
>   because your app basically lives on a tiny desert island in which you
>   are the only Instagram user and only your past twenty posts exist. So,
>   for example, the /media/search endpoint will only return the media you
>   uploaded near a given location, excluding the media from everyone else
>   or any posts beyond your last twenty.

...

> Sandbox users are other Instagram users that you “invite” to your
>   client. The main reason to do this is so that your app will then be
>   able to “see” their last twenty posts in addition to your own. In
>   other words, when they accept the invitation, they show up on the tiny
>   desert island where your app lives.

Comment: Is the application process to "Go Live" mainly for full fledged products, or could I get approved with just a couple hundred lines of code that are flung together? I'd like to gain access to more scopes than basic for a personal project.

Comment: Their policy does not have any requirements about the size of your app. But the use cases they will consider are very narrow. And even if your use case matches (spoiler: it won't) you'll have trouble getting something "flung together" through the submission process because they require videos demonstrating the exact functionality for each scope. HOWEVER... remember that you CAN request scopes WITHOUT going live. Scopes and "live" aren't technically connected. But if you're in sandbox mode, you will only be able to see your own data. The article I linked to explains it better.

Comment: @emersonthis Thanks! I'm in sandbox mode, I've included permission scope for `follower_list`, yet I'm getting back an empty JSON object from my query: `{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}`. I was thinking that this was because I had to "Go live" in order to use the scopes, but that is not the case. It's probably a bug in my code.

Comment: Are you testing as yourself (or whichever account was used to register the client)? Unless you've invited other Sandbox users I would expect that you see results when YOU log in but not when anyone else does. The linked article explains why Sandbox mode would cause that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In production mode, you will see all the users, in sandbox mode you will only see the users that you have added to sandbox.

Comment: Hii, sorry if it sounds a little bit dubious but did you find that on an application that run in production? Is the application running under the new Instagram policies? @krisrak